# How to use cache to store query results in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-6

Hello I have been trying to cache this query return for a few hours without success.

```
        $data = $query->groupBy('visits.images_id')
    ->orderByRaw('COUNT(visits.images_id) desc')
    ->select('images.*')
    ->paginate($settings->result_request)->onEachSide(1);

    return $data;
```

i know it works somehow with this but i am still a beginner in php and have no idea how to write the code.

```
Cache::remember
```

Can anyone help me? I would be really grateful to find someone who could also program things for my laravel app from time to time in exchange for money. Have a great day everyone and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
    $data = cache()->remember('data', now()->addMinutes(<minutes_to_remember_the_cache_for>), function () {
return $query->groupBy('visits.images_id')
    ->orderByRaw('COUNT(visits.images_id) desc')
    ->select('images.*')
    ->paginate($settings->result_request)->onEachSide(1);
});
```

This should do the trick ...

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you'd want to cache the `get` results.

```php
// This would become your query builder. There's no need to cache this
// as this is just a builder.
 $builder = $query->groupBy('visits.images_id')
    ->orderByRaw('COUNT(visits.images_id) desc')
    ->select('images.*');

dd($builder); // To see the SQL
```

Next, I'd create a repository.

```php
namespace App\Repositories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class QueryRepository
{

  public function paginate(Builder $builder, $extraParams, string $key)
  {
      return cache()->remember($key, 'SOME-SECONDS', function() use($builder, $extraParams) {
          return $builder->paginate($extraParams)->onEachSide(1);
      });
  }

}
```

Usage:

```php
use App\Repositories\QueryRepository;

$repository = new QueryRepository;

$extraParams = $settings->result_request;
$data = $repository->paginate($builder, $extraParams, 'UNIQUE-KEY-THAT-SHAPES-THIS-QUERY');
```